# Support for RTP/RTSP in WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

I have a C++ code which provides a live RTP/RTSP video stream and want to transpile that code to web assembly.
So, before doing that I want to know whether web assembly support RTP/RTSP Live streaming or I have to make Changes in my Code for Live Streaming?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebAssembly is a simple assembly language, it supports computations based on a few core types, and that's it! You can export WebAssembly functions to make them callable by JavaScript, and import JavaScript functions to make them callable from WebAssembly (with type restrictions).

So no, it does not support RTP/RTSP - it is likely that you will have to do quite a bit of work to make this work. One option is to use WebSockets to stream the data, then handle the protocol logic within WebAssembly.